# Map two enumerations to a third single enumeration

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, enumeration

What would be the best way in C# to map a combination of two enumerations to a third enumeration?

Basically I need a class with a static method that can accept EnumerationA and EnumerationB and in that method or class have a static mapping for what enumeration should return for X,Y combination.

Does anyone have any good examples?

Comment: I'm thinking if a Dictionary<Tuple<EnumA,EnumB>,EnumC> would solve my problem.  Efficiently, I'm unsure.

Comment: Vote to close for lack of clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is really unclear, but here's some guess at what you want.

```
public enum A { X, ... }
public enum B { Y, Z, ... }
public enum C { Cat, Dog, ... }

private static readonly Dictionary<Tuple<A, B>, C> lookup =
    new Dictionary<Tuple<A, B>, C>
    {
        { Tuple.Create(A.X, B.Y), C.Cat },
        { Tuple.Create(A.X, B.Z), C.Dog },
        ...etc...
    };

public static C Lookup(A a, B b)
{
    return lookup[Tuple.Create(a, b)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't [Enumerable.Concat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) what you want?

The documentation has C# examples (along with others).

Comment: Sorry my description needs improving.  I am trying to create a mapping.  Say enumeration A is Animals and B is Foods.  If someone passes in Animals.Dogs, Foods.Treats, then reference a value from a third enumeration called BowserTreats.